# How I can fix APPCRASH in game.exe?

Tags: crash

I downloaded this game 'City Racing' from gametop.com but when I'm running it isn't starting. The message says 'city racing has stopped working. check online for solution.' But when I'm checking nothing happens.

**This is the detail-**
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: game.exe
  Application Version:  1.0.0.1
  Application Timestamp:    4ee6fe80
  Fault Module Name:    game.exe
  Fault Module Version: 1.0.0.1
  Fault Module Timestamp:   4ee6fe80
  Exception Code:   c0000005
  Exception Offset: 0000543c
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1
  Locale ID:    16393
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

**Game requirements are:**
 Windows 95/98/XP/ME/Vista/7;
- Processor 800 Mhz or better;
- RAM: minimum 1024Mb;
- DirectX 9.0 or higher;
- DirectX compatible sound board.

And I'm meeting all requirements.

Comment: TBH that website seems fishy.

Answer (score 2):

There's no real way to fix this problem short of communicating with the game developer, who should be able (if willing) to investigate further based on the crash report, and identify the cause.